# fetch in scrapy shell is not updating objects.What am I missing here?

Tags: shell, scrapy, ipython

I am opening the scrapy shell as follows

```
scrapy shell "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/"
```

Which gives me:

```
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   hxs        <HtmlXPathSelector xpath=None data=u'<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Ty'>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/>
[s]   settings   <CrawlerSettings module=None>
[s]   spider     <BaseSpider 'default' at 0x9e1d3ec>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser


In [1]: hxs.select('//title')
Out[1]: [<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//title' data=u'<title>Open Directory - Computers: Progr'>]
```

The title from the response is as expected:

```
In [1]: hxs.select('//title')
Out[1]: [<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//title' data=u'<title>Open Directory - Computers: Progr'>]
```

Now I follow this up with a simple fetch:

```
In [2]: fetch("http://www.google.com")
```

The shell output suggests that the objects have been updated:

```
In [2]: fetch("http://www.google.com")
2013-10-18 23:10:09+0530 [default] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=eHJhUo2sOobSrQeM5ICAAg> from <GET http://www.google.com>
2013-10-18 23:10:09+0530 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=eHJhUo2sOobSrQeM5ICAAg> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   hxs        <HtmlXPathSelector xpath=None data=u'<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://sche'>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://www.google.com>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=eHJhUo2sOobSrQeM5ICAAg>
[s]   settings   <CrawlerSettings module=None>
[s]   spider     <BaseSpider 'default' at 0x9e1d3ec>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

However, I find that they haven't. view(response) shows me the dmoz page

And extracting the title gives the same old one:

```
In [3]: hxs.select('//title')
Out[3]: [<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//title' data=u'<title>Open Directory - Computers: Progr'>]
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: What scrapy/python/ipython version are you using? It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it works for me, maybe it is related to this bug: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/396

Could you try running latest dev version?

**UPDATE:** The issue comes with ipython 0.10, update to a recent version and it should work as intended. Also it is fixed in scrapy 0.19+ (latest dev). So you can either upgrade ipython or scrapy.

Comment: Looks like that is the problem. I am using Scrapy 0.18.4 and Ipython 0.10.2 Will try running the latest dev version, thanks.

Comment: Rho, Is there a way I can have both the latest stable version and the development version installed separately? I'd like to stick with the stable version for running scrapers and just want to use the shell part of the dev version.

Comment: Use `virtualenv`: http://warpedtimes.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/a-tutorial-on-virtualenv-to-isolate-python-installations/

Comment: I reproduced your bug with ipython 0.10. If you are using linux and have a recent version of `pip` installed, you can install ipython locally: `pip install --user -U ipython`

Comment: Thanks, I realized I was working with a really old version of ipython and upgraded. Now I seem to have an ipython issue. Trying to run the scrapy shell results in the following error: 

`  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/Magic.py", line 536, in Magic
    @testdec.skip_doctest
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'skip_doctest'
`
Googling this error suggests it's an old and infrequent one. Wondering if this is because I am on an old version of Fedora (15).